# Can we assign both classes and id to Javafx Controls

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2, scenebuilder

Hi there JavaFx community. So I recently shifted from html/javascript to Javafx and using scene builder to create my UI.

My question is, like in html we could assign classes and id to an element, can we do the same in JavaFx, ie assign multiple textfields and buttons the same class? According to what I have seen we cannot assign classes in javafx. I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on it.

I am asking this as having classes for GUI elements in html makes life so much easier so I'm just dumbfounded if javafx doesn't allow us to do this.

Also in that case, what would be good alternative ways around this issue.

Thanks heaps..

Comment: "According to what I have seen we cannot assign classes in javafx." Where did you see this? It is not true.

Answer (score 2):

You can define css classes in JavaFX just like you can in HTML. Have a look at this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm See: "Creating Class Styles"

Comment: Java 8 version of the docs (not sure it is any different): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm#CHDGHCDG

Comment: @mipa firstly thanks for the link. However, what I want to do is have go over all the textboxes and checkboxes that have a specific class and get their value so I can provide a final result. In the case of your link, its more to do with styling than program logic.

Comment: @user7278236 You can use a [`lookup`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-) to do what you describe, but it's not necessarily a good approach. CSS is really for style, not logic. You should probably consider a more object-oriented approach to implementing that functionality, e.g. using inheritance or some kind of creational design pattern.